# Is it possible to disable the RTL (Right To Left -> Arabic language support) in React Native app?

Tags: react-native

In my react-native app, there is a function to change the language into English and Arabic. I want to change only language.
But when I change language, all layout changes into RTL layout design.
How can I disable the RTL? I want to change only language into Arabic.

That is my language.js file.

```
import { I18nManager, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'
import RNRestart from 'react-native-restart'
import strings from '../strings';
import NavigationService from '../navigators/NavigationService';

const defaultLanguageCode = 'ar'

export const languageSwitcher = {
    async startup() {
        const languageCode = await this.getCurrentLanguageCode()
        await this.switchTo(languageCode)
    },
    async switchTo(languageCode) {
        strings.setLanguage(languageCode)
        await this.saveLanguageCode(languageCode)
        // allowRTL(false);
        const rtlLangCodes = ['ar']
        const selectedLanIsRTL = rtlLangCodes.includes(languageCode)
        // Restart App If necessary
        const { isRTL, forceRTL, allowRTL } = I18nManager
        if (selectedLanIsRTL !== isRTL) {
            //allowRTL(false)
            //forceRTL(false)
            allowRTL(selectedLanIsRTL)
            forceRTL(selectedLanIsRTL)
            setTimeout(() => RNRestart.Restart(), 1);
        }
    },
    // English And Arabic Toggle
    async toggleLanguages() {
        let languageCode = await AsyncStorage.getItem('languageCode')
        if (languageCode === defaultLanguageCode) {
            languageCode = 'ar'
        } else {
            languageCode = defaultLanguageCode
        }
        await this.switchTo(languageCode)
    },
    async getCurrentLanguageCode() {
        let languageCode = await AsyncStorage.getItem('languageCode')
        if (!languageCode) { languageCode = defaultLanguageCode }
        return languageCode
    },
    async saveLanguageCode(languageCode) {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('languageCode', languageCode, (error) => {
            if (error) { throw error }
        })
    },
}
```

Comment: Just curious but if you want to switch the language to an RTL language shouldn't the layout also update? Otherwise the layout makes no sense for your RTL language users right?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes. you are right. But I want to change only language. I wanna disable the layout change.

Comment: Right I understand what you want to do but I don't understand why really. RTL language users expect a specific layout for their language and you seem to want to break that expectation, why? Again, just curious :)

Comment: Yes, I also curious, But it must be done like that. Is there any way to disable only layout?
Thank you again

Comment: Sorry, it's not my area, I focus on user experience mostly, I can't help you with React, hopefully you will find an answer here :)